# index was outside the bounds of the array because of \n (new line) in richTextBox

Tags: c#

If i go into the next line with richTextBox1.Text + "\n" you can't use richTextBox with anything anymore normally.
Why not ? because index will be outside the bounds of the array and you won't be able to transport the data into database or work with it normally...it will be all messed up. It is like the story with cin and getline in C++, but much worse. Here you won't see errors, not until you'll try to transport it into database. If you use "\n" to write new lines into txt, your txt will be also unusable. It will look like up to the byte the same as if you would write it by hand same sentences but "\n" will break it.

So how do i go into the next line and not have this "\n" screwing up my program ??!
How do i go into the new line ?

Comment: This sounds like a problem somewhere else in your code. Where are you having problems?

Comment: I tried to write my code in many ways, but fact is that if i save from richTextBox + "\n" to txt as just a simple word like: aaa it won't be the same as if i open a txt and write aaa inside. I can write anything into txt and import in any way to database but if i use "\n" it will be unusable.

Comment: Anyway i solved the problem how to go to new line, but i had to use vectors workaround instead of "\n" which pisses me off.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what platform you're on, there is a difference between `"\n"` and `Environment.NewLine`. I would recommend appending to and comparing with Environment.NewLine, although, you may have inconsistent results persisted to your database if you deploy to different platforms.

Comment: i tried System.Environment.NewLine and it was the same, i created a new database, it was the same result.

Comment: i use StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(file). Maybe i should use something else than StreamWriter.